# Make sum for one column based on condition from another column in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one `MySQL` table with two columns: `amount (INT)` and `address (string)`.
All addresses start with "A" or "B".
How can I calculate the sum of all amounts for which address starts with "A" and sum of all amounts for which address start with "B"?

I would prefer to do this in `PHP` rather than in `MySQL` directly.

Comment: use aggregate functions such as `COUNT()` and `SUM()`, then update your post after if  you encountered any problems. In PHP, it's also `count()` with `+=`.

Comment: Using SQL aggregate functions and group by.... `SELECT address,SUM(amount) FROM table GROUP BY address` is far easier than doing it in PHP

Comment: If you really need to do it in PHP, use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), and then a combination of [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to retrieve the amounts, and then [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) on the results

Comment: I'm mystified by the final sentence

Comment: Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608944/make-sum-for-one-column-based-on-condition-from-another-column-in-php/48610204#48610204) @NewGuy for a `PHP` solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the `PHP` request is not mandatory, you could simply do it with `SQL`.

You could use `left` and `group by`:

```
select left(address, 1) addr_part, sum(amount)
from my_table
group by addr_part
```

Comment: *"I would prefer to do this in PHP rather than in mysql directly."*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - although when somebody posts a question with that kind of restriction, it's always a good idea to discover why the restriction

Comment: @MarkBaker and we probably won't find out what that restriction is; which is why I had left the question after. Maybe the OP's doing what I suggested they do, that's also an unknown ;-)

Comment: My was   a suggestion in case  php is not mandatory  .. answer updated  with this comment ..

Answer (score 0):

Doing it directly in `MySQL`, see [scaisEdge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48608973/6313073), is the way to go in my opinion, but since you want a `PHP` solution, you can try the following:

```
<?php
   # Create an array to store the results.
   $data = ["A" => 0, "B" => 0];

   # Initiate a db connection.
   $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "db");

   # Fetch the addresses and amounts from the database.
   $result = $connection -> query("SELECT `address`, `amount` FROM `table_name`");

   # Iterate over each row.
   while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
      # Increment the value by the amount of the row.
      $data[$row["address"][0]] += $row["amount"];
   }
?>
```